# f# allow cors web api

Tags: f#, cors, c#-to-f#

I am currently developing a web api using f#, I am totally new to it as I am coming from a c# background, and I would like to fetch datas from a reactjs application.
But I need to allow cors on my f# webapi. I am totally lost when I am trying to allow cors.
So far, I added :

```
member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddCors() |> ignore
```

and I have tried to add

```
app.UseCors() |> ignore
```

to the configure member, but I don't understand how to implement this method to allow cors in my application.
I have also tried to add

```
[<EnableCors("...")>]
```

on my controller but I don't know what to put inside it

Any help would be very appreciate

Edit 1:
So far here is what I have :

```
module ConfigurationCors =
    let ConfigureCors(corsBuilder: CorsPolicyBuilder): unit =        
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials() |> ignore

open ConfigurationCors

type Startup private () =
    new (configuration: IConfiguration) as this =
        Startup() then
        this.Configuration <- configuration 

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddCors() |> ignore


services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1) |> ignore


// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IHostingEnvironment) =
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) then
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() |> ignore
    else
        app.UseHsts() |> ignore
    app.UseHttpsRedirection() |> ignore
    app.UseMvc() |> ignore
    app.UseCors(Action<CorsPolicyBuilder> ConfigureCors) |> ignore

member val Configuration : IConfiguration = null with get, set
```

I have instanciate a module and a function inside it that I am passing to UseCors but it seems it's not working, is it the good way ? If someone has a hint and could help me.

Here is my fetch method in my react app :

```
 fetch('https://localhost:44323/api/values')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
```

Comment: What library are you using? That looks like Giraffe, but is it Giraffe or something else?

Comment: I am not using any library, just the defaut asp net f# project

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1), I suspect you should call `UseCors` middleware before `UseMvc`:

```
app.UseCors(Action<CorsPolicyBuilder> ConfigureCors)
   .UseMvc()
   .UseHttpsRedirection()
```

Below is my first answer, so I'd like to leave it as a general solution to server-side CORS.

To allow CORS on the server side, you'll have to set the response's headers `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` to `"*"` (or limit to a set of allowed origins).

Here is a barebone HttpListener that sets the headers to `HttpListenerResponse`:

```
module Server

open System
open System.Net

type HttpHandler = (HttpListenerRequest -> HttpListenerResponse -> Async<unit>)

type HttpListener with
    static member Run (url: string, handler: HttpHandler) =
        let listener = new HttpListener ()
        listener.Prefixes.Add url
        listener.Start ()
        let asynctask = Async.FromBeginEnd(listener.BeginGetContext, listener.EndGetContext)
        async {
            while true do
                let! ctx = asynctask
                // Add the headers here
                ctx.Response.AddHeader ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                Async.Start (handler ctx.Request ctx.Response)
        } |> Async.Start
        listener

let run port = 
    HttpListener.Run ("http://localhost" + port + "/", fun req res ->
        async {
            let out = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes "Hello, Mars!"
            res.OutputStream.Write (out, 0, out.Length)
            res.OutputStream.Close()
        }
    ) |> ignore
    printfn "Running server on localhost:%s" port
    Console.Read () |> ignore

// Main.fs

open Server

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Server.run ":3000"
    0
```

If you run a curl client with `curl http://localhost:3000 -v` you should be able to inspect the CORS headers in the response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll have a try when i get home, but does it works if you tried to access the value from let's say http://localhost:3000 ? And I don't really see how i can apply this to the default web api project generated by visual studio

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerresponse.addheader?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_HttpListenerResponse_AddHeader_System_String_System_String_ this is actually in the MSDN doc. You just need to add the CORS headers before returning `HttpListenerResponse`. You could run the server on any port you'd like (except reserved ones of coures).